# Detecting outliers in non parametric data

Tags: spss, nonparametric, outliers

what is the best (and easy) way to detect outliers in spss for skewed, not exactly normally distributed data?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I mainly need it for logistic regression an I assume that even tho logistic r. does not assume normality I still need to make sure that there are no extreme outliers

Comment: The adjectives "parametric" and "nonparametric" don't apply to data. Can you explain what you mean without any technical terms? Your comment should be rewritten as a complete English sentence or sentences and included in your question.

Comment: Hi, I have a group of people and recorded their ages, size of tumor and so on, which is non normally distributed when I check for skewness etc. Eventually I would like to run a logistic regression e.g. and therefore would like to see if there are any outliers that have to be dealt with. Hope this is a bit clearer now.

Comment: BTW I apologize to anybody that feels highly offended but please notice that I already asked this question in a different forum and also asked more than one good friend of mine for help. This seems to disturb certain people to whom I want to express my sympathy.

Comment: "not normal" is not the same thing as 'nonparametric'. You can say "not normal", but most people wouldn't expect tumor size to be normal in any case. However, you should note that in regression, (1) the distribution of y (the marginal distribution) is not itself assumed to be normal, so looking at histograms or QQ plots or calculating the skewness of the response doesn't tell you if the distributional assumption was violated anyway; (2) there's no assumption whatever about the distribution of the x-variables.

Comment: What's the 0-1 response in the [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression)? Which other forum did you ask in?

Comment: I think I just drop my concern. I heard that as long as it is not extremely skewed it is ok not to check for outliers also an not because its very difficult with non normally distributed data.

Comment: But anyway response would be different kind of complications y/n. Thanks